# Awk match column using variable and word boundaries

Tags: awk

I am trying to print lines where the first column contains a match with "var" using boundaries.

```
awk -F '|' '$1 ~ /\<$var\>/ { print $0 }'
```

It works as expected without trying to use a variable.

```
echo "18,19,20|hello world" |  awk -F '|' '$1 ~ /\<18\>/ { print $0 }'
18,19,20|hello world
```

How can I do it using my variable?

Comment: 100% works on my linux ubuntu. Doesn't work on my mac though.

Comment: The version without the variable works for me, with GNU Awk 5.0.1. In the version with the `$var`, however, where is the value of `$var` coming from? If there is no parameter lie `-v var=val`, it is unclear to me where `$var` would be set.

Comment: OK, indeed, that is a feature of GNU awk. Won't work with minimal awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F '|' -v var="$var" '$1 ~ ("\\<"var"\\>")'
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps